# WCF using Async/Await - Channel blocked in Client

Tags: wcf, asynchronous, task, block

I'm working with .Net 4.5 and my services are written using Async and returning Task<>.
When I call the service from the client I use await.
When the service returns after the await it seems that the channel is blocked if the client code calls another operation which is not async.

Sample code:

```
value = await Service.InitAsync();
Service.SyncOperation(); // Further callbacks/return values from Server are blocked and this statement never returns
```

(The whole point of async/await as I see it is to allow me to write the full flow in one method and let the framework deal with threads and callbacks)

I was able to solve this by wrapping the call to the service with a new task and then Task.Yield:

```
async Task<T> CallAsync<T>(Func<Task<T>> func)
{
    Task<T> t = await func;
    await Task.Yield();
    return t;
}
```

and in the client:

```
value = CallAsync(Service.InitAsync);
Service.SyncOperation(); //Now the server is not blocked since Yield changed back to the client context.
```

My question is, is there any other way to do this without wrapping the Service call in the Client?
Maybe some attribute or property in the Service?

Thanks

Comment: What does this event represent? When does it get set?

Comment: Currently I only have one case where this happens and the event is set immediately. However, as I build the system I don't want to limit myself to writing code that calls async WCF methods and not be able to do long operations after the await.

Comment: I changed the sample code and removed the event to show a more common scenario

Comment: So you call the service at first async, but then sync. And you expect not to be blocked although you call a sync method? I'm confused. Why don't you always use await async?

Comment: Of course I expect the client is blocked when I call a sync method, hwoever I didn't expect the return channel of the server to also be blocked. I thought the server would be able to continue sending callbacks and return values for other calls.

Comment: When you say `value = CallAsync(Service.InitAsync);`, are you aware that init did not necessarily finish executing at this point because you did not await/wait the task?; My understanding is that you need to configure your service with `ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant` to have reentrant callbacks. Taken from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx